# Using proxy with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, proxy, nodemailer

When I used nodemailer with proxy or without proxy, I did not have a problem.

But I used that with this form did not have a problem.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: server.host,
    port: server.port,
    secure: server.secure, // true for 465, false for other ports
    proxy:`http://${AllProxies[count].toString()}`,
    auth: {
        user: user, // generated ethereal user
        pass: pass // generated ethereal password
    }
});
transporter.onCreateSocket = function(callback) {
   var socket = openProxyConnection(function() {
      callback(null, {
         connection: socket
      });
   });
};
```

When I open `console.log()`, it shows IP same as when I input IP with hand.

I get this error:

> Line: 0; Error: Error: Invalid response from proxy: 403
> at Socket.onSocketData (/****/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/http-proxy-client.js:118:37)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)